# QThreadPrivate::finish segmentation fault in static object destructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I've got following simplified code (in original project the code if more complicated):

```
namespace show_msg_thread
{
class CShowMsg
{
public:
    CShowMsg() = default;
    ~CShowMsg() = default;

    CShowMsg(const CShowMsg&) = delete;
    CShowMsg& operator=(const CShowMsg&) = delete;

    void WaitUntilProcessed()
    {
        m_event.Wait();
    }

    void ProcessInCurrentThread()
    {
        {
            int argc = 1;
            char arg0[] = "TestAppLinux";

            char* argv[] = { arg0};

            QApplication app(argc, argv);
            QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::Warning, QString::fromWCharArray(L"LinuxTestApp"),
                               QString("Test message"), QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
            msgBox.exec();
        }
        m_event.Set();
    }

private:
    Event m_event;
};

class CShowThread
{
public:
    CShowThread(const CShowThread&) = delete;
    CShowThread& operator=(const CShowThread&) = delete;

    void EnqueueRequest(CShowMsg* pRequest)
    {
        {
            std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> guard(m_msgMutex);
            m_msgPtr = pRequest;
        }
        m_msgEvent.Set();
    }

    static CShowThread& Instance()
    {
        static CShowThread instance;
        return instance;
    }

private:
    CShowThread()
        : m_bAtomicStopThread(false)
    {
        m_thread = std::thread(&CShowThread::ProcessShowReportRequests, this);
    }

    ~CShowThread()
    {
        m_bAtomicStopThread = true;

        m_msgEvent.Set();
        m_thread.join();
    }

    void ProcessShowReportRequests()
    {
        do
        {
            m_msgEvent.Wait();

            while (true)
            {
                CShowMsg* pCurrentMsg = nullptr;
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_msgMutex);

                    if(m_msgPtr != nullptr)
                    {
                        pCurrentMsg = m_msgPtr;
                        m_msgPtr = nullptr;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
                if(pCurrentMsg != nullptr)
                    pCurrentMsg->ProcessInCurrentThread();
            }
        } while (!m_bAtomicStopThread);
    }

private:
    std::thread m_thread;
    std::atomic_bool m_bAtomicStopThread;

    CShowMsg* m_msgPtr = nullptr;
    std::mutex m_msgMutex;
    Event m_msgEvent;
};

void Initialize()
{
    CShowThread::Instance();
}

void ShowDialog()
{
    CShowMsg msg;
    CShowThread::Instance().EnqueueRequest(&msg);
    msg.WaitUntilProcessed();
}
```

}

```
int main()
{
    {
        show_msg_thread::Initialize();
        show_msg_thread::ShowDialog();
    }
    std::cout << "Finished" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here `Event` is just wrapper class around `std::conditional_variable`.

When singleton instance is terminated there is a segmentation fault. So I see in output `Finished` string. Then destructor of `CShowThread` is called and segmentation fault is occurred.
If I comment QApplication creation (and showing QMessageBox) in `ProcessInCurrentThread` function then everything is fine. However when I uncomment only QApplication creation then the problem occurs.
Here is what I managed to see in debugger: [image]

As it seen from the callstack, my app crashes in `QThreadPrivate::finish` method, but I wasn't able to find the reason.

Could u please tell why this happens?

**UPD:** I tried following snippet, like @Ipiano suggested:

```
void ProcessInCurrentThread() 
{ 
    { 
        int argc = 1; 
        char arg0[] = "TestAppLinux"; 

        char* argv[] = { arg0}; 

        QApplication app(argc, argv); 

        QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::Warning, QString::fromWCharArray(L"LinuxTestApp"), 
                         QString("Test message"), QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No); 

        QTimer::singleShot(0, [&msgBox, &app, this](){ 
            m_promiseResult.set_value(msgBox.exec() == QMessageBox::Yes); 
            app.quit(); 
        }); 

        app.exec(); 
    } 
    m_event.Set(); 
}
```

But still got the same error

Comment: The way you use `QApplication` is really weird (to me).  Do you ever call `exec` on it?

Comment: I would advise against creating a local QApplication and against create a QApplication inside a thread. What about creating the QApplication inside your `main()` function instead?

Comment: @DanM. I call `exec` for `QMessageBox ` object. But `QApplication` should be created before this call. @vdavid, I inserted here simplified code. In real project this code runs in shared lib, so there is no `main()`. I agree that the architecture of the app is weird, but there is nothing I can do with it (at least now)

Comment: Is the core of the project (wherever main() is) a Qt application? Does that create and exec a `QApplication`? If so, you're going to have all sorts of weirdness with multiple `QApplication` instances. If not, then this is a bit more reasonable; I've had to do some screwy stuff like this to run a library built on Qt in a non-Qt application. I suspect @DanM. is right and you need to call `QApplication::exec()` before the dialog is executed. This could potentially be done with `QTimer::singleshot` to trigger a lambda to show the dialog and then call `QApplication::quit()` within `app.exec()`

Comment: @Ipiano, no app with `main()` isn't Qt application. My library (where QApplication is created and dialog is shown) used to collect some info and show report dialog in another threat. So any app can use this lib in own purposes. Thus lib should be able to show dialog with report. If I call `app.exec()` before `msgBox.exec()` then I don't see the dialog.

Comment: Re. `"...show report dialog in another thread"`:  creating/using any `QWidget` or derived class instance in a thread other than that on which `main` is running is not supported.

Comment: As noted by @G.M., using `QWidget` outside of the main thread is not supported. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html. However, I was curious if this could work anyway, and while it's not supported... it does work*. @rudolfninja, you said calling `app.exec()` results in nothing. This is probably because that starts the Qt event loop, and then doesn't return. But it is possible to queue up a timer, which shows the dialog from within the event loop.

Comment: In my example, that looked like this
`QTimer::singleShot(0, [&msgBox, &app, &promise = m_result_promise]() { promise.set_value(msgBox.exec()); app->quit(); }); app->exec();`
And it does work; it shows the dialog, and then exits; and I can even do this multiple times. However, when the main thread exits, I get a warning `QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread`. This is because there's a global static object that gets deleted in the application exit. This is why what you are trying to do is not supported.

Comment: The other issue with this approach is that it is strictly incompatible with Qt applications. If you tried to use this dialog thread in a project which was already running a Qt application for other stuff, it would have issues because you create a second `QApplication` when the dialog is shown.

Comment: @Ipiano, thanks. Will try your advise and will keep in mind warning about 2nd instance of `QApplication`

Comment: @Ipiano, I updated my initial post with code, I tried according to your suggestions, but it didn't help. May be I did something wrong

Comment: Well given that what I suggested isn't officially supported; I wouldn't be surprised to find out that something in your environment breaks it. Maybe you're on a different OS, than I am; maybe it's something to do with loading a plugin vs building directly. Regardless, you should find a different approach; what you are trying to do is not a valid long-term solution. At the very least, you might need to find some other library than Qt to use as your UI framework so that you can display things from a non-main thread.

Comment: @Ipiano may be the reason is in that, I'm using singleton (e.g. static object, which is destroyed after main function execution). If I change static object of `CShowThread` to non-static one, then everything is ok